# How do I stop autocorrect from inserting incorrect apostrophes

Tags: autocorrect

On both macOS (through Sonoma) and iOS (through 17) autocorrect routinely inserts clearly incorrect apostrophes (e.g. converting "your" to "you're", "its" to "it's") and often vice versa. I have been expecting this to get fixed by an update for years, but the recent comprehensive changes to correction and predictive input prompt to finally ask.

How do I stop autocorrect from inserting incorrect apostrophes?

Comment: I understand it wasn't just Sonoma but do you have Sonoma installed now? Can you name the apps where these happen and any specific circumstances / uses within those apps, if any?

Comment: I turn off predictive text because my grammar skills exceed that provided by predictive text...

Comment: I turned off auto-correct some years ago: but I have set the option so that iOS shows me options above the keyboard, which I can select to complete long words.

Comment: Note those are correct changes in some cases. That is both its and it's are both correct English which is correct depends on context. I would not that you can see anywhere a lot of misuse.

Comment: @mmmmmm Not in these cases (see OP title)